# ActionCable: unsubscribed - Reliable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, websocket, actioncable, unsubscribe

We are building an api where we do need to be able to see if a user is online or not. By using subscribed / unsubscribed we could achieve this pretty easy.

But if connection is lost or severed in some way that does mean that either the client or server is aware of this. Then again, I'm not aware on how often this would be the case.

How reliable is the unsubscribed method in Actioncable when it comes to connection with mobile devices on 3G/4G...5G?

Answer (score 1):

I've observed that this is reliable (it does trigger for every connection severed), but connection is stated as established way too long on my system.
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/27082